# Using Sentry with Codesleeve Stapler?

Tags: laravel, avatar, cartalyst-sentry

### Update #1

So I think I found out where the problem is but since I lack the knowledge, there's no way for me to solve it.

When using Sentry, I've tried extending both 'Model' which is default with the Sentry package and Laravel's 'Eloquent' under `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. Neither worked. But while using Laravel's Eloquent on its own (no Sentry package addons), Stapler works nicely.

So I guess there is some compatibilty problem between Stapler and Sentry's User model even though it uses Eloquent (its extra functionalities might be conflicting with stapler's traits or the construct function, I don't know). Too bad since Sentry is a great package for managing authentication and throttling and is widely used as far as I know.

Is there any easy way to use stapler's agnostic version with sentry or will I have to rewrite all my code to use laravel's auth?

---

### Main question

I'm building an app which uses Cartalyst's Sentry for managing users. However, I want users and other models to be able to have associated avatars, so I'm using Codesleeve's Stapler too.

I've read both [laravel-stapler](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/laravel-stapler)'s readme and most of [stapler](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/stapler/)'s standalone version documentation but couldn't figure out how to make them work with Sentry. Whenever I try to create an user through this function:

```
$user = Sentry::createUser(array(
    'username'      => Input::get('username'),
    'email'         => Input::get('email'),
    'password'      => Input::get('password'),
    'activated'     => false,
    'avatar'        => Input::file('avatar')
));

return 'success';
```

I get:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'avatar' in 'field list'
```

So it seems Sentry is querying as if the avatar is a string and Stapler is not working.

Here is my Sentry user model (which I'm extending in Laravel's):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Codesleeve\Stapler\ORM\StaplerableInterface;
use Codesleeve\Stapler\ORM\EloquentTrait;
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Groups\GroupInterface;
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Hashing\HasherInterface;
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\LoginRequiredException;
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\PasswordRequiredException;
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserAlreadyActivatedException;
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserExistsException;
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserInterface;

class User extends Model implements UserInterface, StaplerableInterface {

        use SoftDeletingTrait, EloquentTrait;

        protected $fillabe = array('username','email','password','password_temp','code','active','avatar');

        public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {
                $this->hasAttachedFile('avatar', [
                    'styles' => [
                        'medium' => '300x300',
                        'thumb' => '100x100'
                    ]
                ]);

                parent::__construct($attributes);
        }
        protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

And inside Sentry's config:

```
'model' => 'Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User',
```

This might be simple to solve since I'm pretty new into Laravel, Sentry and Stapler but I couldn't find any info which would make me solve the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done.  Based on what's in your OP, the root cause appears to be that your user model doesn't know that `avatar` is a Stapler-provided column.

Theory: the Sentry User Provider manufactures a user model, [right here](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/blob/2.1/src/Cartalyst/Sentry/Users/Eloquent/Provider.php#L317).  That user model must be Stapler-aware, per the [Stapler docs](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/stapler/blob/master/docs/setup.md#traitsdrivers).  Fortunately, Sentry is configurable and you can tell it to use your custom model with [setModel()](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/blob/2.1/src/Cartalyst/Sentry/Users/Eloquent/Provider.php#L330).

Rough outline of solution:  First, you need a model that is Stapler-aware.  You might already have this.  Note that it extends the Sentry-provided model class and also imports the Stapler trait.  *Both are important.*

```
<?php // app/models/UserModel.php
namespace App\Model;
use Codesleeve\Stapler\ORM\StaplerableInterface;
use Codesleeve\Stapler\ORM\EloquentTrait;
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User as SentryUserModel;

class UserModel extends SentryUserModel implements StaplerableInterface {
    use EloquentTrait;
}
```

Second, you need to instruct Sentry to use this.  Below I use run-time configuration changes, as is my preference.  But you can also [change the Sentry configuration file](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/extend-user-model-for-sentry):

```
<?php // app/bootstrap.php

\Sentry::getUserProvider()->setModel('App\Model\UserModel');
```

I'm doing this from memory on Laravel 4, so there may need to be some tweaking involved.